# Infinite space, nothingness, and the concept of infinity

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe

These two questions are a follow-up to my previous Phys.SE [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141835/2451) on finite space.

1. The first question challenges the concept of infinite space. Space is something: it is ruled by laws, and contains an inflation field according the latest cosmology model.  Why can't space be finite and enclosed by Nothing (no field, no laws)? Nothing then would be infinite, continuing forever - to me this does not seem anymore  more extraordinary than an infinite space.
2. The second question challenges the concept of infinity: is there anything truly infinite in the physical world, for example, the number of particles  or a true spatial continuum with an infinite number of points? (Question is a quote from Max Tegmark). If there is no physical equivalence, how can space be infinite?

Comment: I am writing a paper analyzing the base assumptions supporting multiverse options. Thus, the finite/infinity issue is critical. The first question resulted from thinking about chaotic inflation which assumes a scalar hypothetical field in all of space. Thus, space has attributes and is not Nothing. I did not find related questions posted. 
In the second question, I was looking for opinions on infinity which exists in mathematics but may not have a  physical counterpart. This may  be metaphysics.
Hope this clarifies.  Appreciated other responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions are in no way challenging. The answer to both questions is 
the same: it could be, we do not know.
Actually, you could also ask the opposite: how do we know that physical space is equivalent to the continuum (the real line) instead of being a larger infinite (by this a mean an ordered field of larger cardinality, such as the surreal line)